# Generating n-grams from a string

Tags: python, string, nlp, n-gram

I need to make a list of all   -grams beginning at the head of string for each integer    from 1 to M. Then return a tuple of M such lists.

```
    def letter_n_gram_tuple(s, M):
        s = list(s)
        output = []
    for i in range(0, M+1):

        output.append(s[i:])

    return(tuple(output))
```

From `letter_n_gram_tuple("abcd", 3)` output should be:

```
(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], ['ab', 'bc', 'cd'], ['abc', 'bcd']))
```

However, my output is:

```
(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], ['b', 'c', 'd'], ['c', 'd'], ['d']).
```

Should I use string slicing and then saving slices into the list?

Comment: You got 15 rep, it would be worth to up-vote everybody.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use nested for, first for about n-gram, second to slice the string

```
def letter_n_gram_tuple(s, M):
    output = []

    for i in range(1, M + 1):
        gram = []
        for j in range(0, len(s)-i+1):
            gram.append(s[j:j+i])
        output.append(gram)

    return tuple(output)
```

or just one line by list comprehension:

```
output = [[s[j:j+i] for j in range(0, len(s)-i+1)] for i in range(1, M + 1)]
```

or use [`windowed`](https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#windowing) in `more_itertools`:

```
import more_itertools
output = [list(more_itertools.windowed(s, i)) for i in range(1, M + 1)]
```

test and output:

```
print(letter_n_gram_tuple("abcd", 3))
(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], ['ab', 'bc', 'cd'], ['abc', 'bcd'])
```

Answer (score 2):

You need one more `for` loop to iterate over letters or `str` :

```
def letter_n_gram_tuple(s, M):
    output = []
    for i in range(0, M):
        vals = [s[j:j+i+1] for j in range(len(s)) if len(s[j:j+i+1]) == i+1]
        output.append(vals)

    return tuple(output)

print(letter_n_gram_tuple("abcd", 3))
```

Output:

```
(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], ['ab', 'bc', 'cd'], ['abc', 'bcd'])
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the below fuction:

```
def letter_n_gram_tuple(s, M):
    s = list(s)
    output = [s]
    for i in range(M + 1):
        output.append([''.join(sorted(set(a + b), key=lambda x: (a + b).index(x))) for a, b in zip(output[-1], output[-1][1:])])
    return tuple(filter(lambda x: len(x) > 1, output))
```

And now:

```
print(letter_n_gram_tuple('abcd',3))
```

Returns:

```
(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], ['ab', 'bc', 'cd'], ['abc', 'bcd'])
```

Answer (score 2):

```
def n_grams(word,max_size):
    i=1
    output=[]
    while i<= max_size:
        index = 0
        innerArray=[]
        while index < len(word)-i+1:
            innerArray.append(word[index:index+i])
            index+=1
        i+=1
        output.append(innerArray)
        innerArray=[]
    return tuple(output)
print(n_grams("abcd",3))
```